# Twitter OAuth Values

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

My goal is to post a comment on a user's twitter page. Here I have this php code...

```
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
'consumer_key' => 'CONSUMER_KEY',
'consumer_secret' => 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
'user_token' => 'USER_TOKEN',
'user_secret' => 'USER_SECRET',
```

));

Is the consumer key and consumer secret the values I get when creating an application from https://dev.twitter.com/apps ?

Then the user token and user secret would be the person twitter account that i'm trying to post a comment on?

I created a dev twitter application and put in the consumer key/secret from the OAuth settings, and create my access token and put the "Access token" and "Access token secret" as the users. Then when running the script, it gave me a Response code:401

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. If anyone cares, you have to go to your application and go to the settings page to make sure it has read and write access.